# Arduino EthernetServer read() only works when Serial is initialized and read characters are printed

Tags: c, embedded, serial-port, arduino, ethernet

I have an Arduino project where I read data from a webserver.

I have an `EthernetClient` that reads the data character by character in a callback  function.

My working code looks like (only the relevant parts):

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ...
}

void loop() {
  char* processedData = processData(callback); // this is in a external lib
}

boolean callback(char* buffer, int& i) {
  ...

  if (Client.available()) {
    char c      = client.read();
    buffer[i++] = c;

    Serial.print(c);
  }

  ...
}
```

This works without any problems (reading and processing the data), but when I remove `Serial.begin(9600);` and `Serial.print(c);` it stops working and I don't know why? The only thing changed is that the `char c` is not printed. What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't know the Arduino API, is Serial.begin() initializing the Ethernet peripheral or is this just for a UART serial monitor (as the baudrate 9600 hints at)?

Comment: I think thats only for UART, I call `Ethernet.begin(macAddress)` after that.

Comment: Btw, why is this tagged C? It is C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common reason why callback functions change their behavior when seemingly unrelated code is altered, is optimizer-related bugs.

Many embedded compilers fail to understand that a callback function (or an interrupt service routine) will ever be called in the program. They see no explicit call to that function and then assumes it is never called.

When the compiler has made such an assumption, it will optimize variables that are changed by the callback function, because it fails to see that the variable is changed by the program, between the point of initialization and the point of access.

```
// Bad practice example:

int x; 

void main (void)
{
  x=5;
  ...

  if(x == 0) /* this whole if statement will get optimized away, 
                the compiler assumes that x has never been changed. */
  {
    do_stuff();
  }
}

void callback (void)
{
  x = 0;
}
```

When this bug strikes, it is nearly impossible to find, it can cause any kind of weird symptoms.

The solution is to *always* declare all file scope ("global") variables shared between main() and an interrupt/callback/thread as `volatile`. This makes it impossible for the compiler to make incorrect optimizer assumptions.

---

(Please note that the `volatile` keyword  cannot be used to achieve synchronization nor does it guarantee any memory barriers. *This answer is not in the slightest related to such issues!*)

Comment: Optimization issues do warrant looking into, but note that there are no variables shared between the callback and other portions of the program in this case, so that proposed criteria for what to declare volatile would not be applicable.  objdumping the result of the compilation would be worthwhile, though the Arduino IDE's tendency to build in a temp folder and burn from there without making the object location obvious can make it a bit frustrating.

Comment: Sry, but there are no global variables shared with the callback, it should just add a characted to the buffer, increase the integer value by the amount of caracters added and return true (or false if no characters was added). So it only has a return value and to values passed by reference.

Comment: @tbraun89 If the buffer is shared with main() you still have the very same problem that is described here. And what about the Ethernet, does it have callbacks/interrupts too?

Comment: No there is no other callback or interrupt, I'm gonna check this with the buffer when I am back at the office tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: Because without the serial driver started, there is no data to process, and therefore your callback is not hit.

What were you hoping the serial callback to be doing in the absence of data?

Providing more information about `Client` and `processData` may help.

Comment: So this means I always have to initialize the serial driver when I want to use the Ethernet library?

Comment: It really depends on what ProcessData is doing.  When is it supposed to trigger the callback?    Also, is `loop` called in a loop?

Comment: `loop` is running all the time so the callback is called everytime one loop is done. The callback should only write the characters into the buffer. If I remove `Serial.println(c)` there is also nothing written into the buffer.

Comment: how is `loop` running all the time?  Is it called inside a `while(1)` or something else?   And are you certain that `callback` is called everytime `processData` is called?  There are no conditions checked?

Comment: That `loop` is running all the time is defined here: http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/loop and the callback get called as the first statement in `processData`. My current solution is to have the `Serial.print` statement in the production version too, does not cost more time to process if no serial adapter is connected and 1k more Flash doesn't matter on a Mega 2560.